# How to use anchor link or HTML in ternary operator in thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot

> I encountered a problem that need to write some HTML codes in ternary operator in Thymeleaf. In where I need to chose an anchor link by using ternary operator. For better understand, I putted those problematic code in below:

```
<span th:text="${error_code == '404'} ? '<a href="http://localhost:8080/home">Home</a>' : '<a href="http://localhost:8080/login">Login</a>'"></span>
```

So, how can I wirte those code correclty in Themeleaf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it :

```
<span th:utext="((${error_code} == '404') ? '<a href=&quot;http://localhost:8080/home&quot;>Home</a>' : '<a href=&quot;http://localhost:8080/login&quot;>Login</a>')"></span>
```

`&quot;` is for  escaping double quote in html.

`utext` is to tell thymeleaf not to print plain text as "< a href.. "